# Apache ProxyPass not forwarding original http headers to workers

Tags: proxypass

I am sending a request to httpd with a setHeader, named.

I see that header if I do not use ModProxy, using getRequestHeader with the header name.

However I need the header information in the ProxyPass workers.

How can I get Apache to forward the headers in ProxyPass.

I have searched for an answer for this for quite a while but I cannot find something that works.

My ProxyPass directive:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
    #No PATH_INFO with mod_proxy_fcgi unless this is set
    SetEnvIf Request_URI . proxy-fcgi-pathinfo=1

    ProxyPass "/gas30/" "fcgi://192.168.1.5:6394/"
    Alias "/gas30" "/opt/fourjs30/gst/gas/bin/fastcgidispatch enablereuse=on"

    ProxyPass "/gas31/" "fcgi://192.168.1.5:6395/"
    Alias "/gas31" "/opt/fourjs31/gst/gas/bin/fastcgidispatch enablereuse=on"

</IfModule>
```

I am using Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS 7)

Thanks in advance

Johan

I use tcpdump to display the header received on Listen port 6380
Just to make sure it is there.

http_auth: Y2FuY3VuQG1ic2JiYW5rLmNvbScgJzExMTExMTExJyAnJDJhJDEyJDJwMlFOMVNZVURldUlpcWw2R3ZWMk83Mi45QUtXSlROcUlnWDRFQVUvZnJjU01SZnJNQXVL

That is the correct header.

I have tried a lot of things to forward that to port 6395.
I am totally stuck on that though.
The last thing I tried was to hard code it under Location.
But I do not see it in tcpdump

```
<Location /gas31>
  Header add http_auth "Y2FuY3VuQG1ic2JiYW5rLmNvbScgJzExMTExMTExJyAnJDJhJDEyJDJwMlFOMVNZVURldUlpcWw2R3ZWMk83Mi45QUtXSlROcUlnWDRFQVUvZnJjU01SZnJNQXVL"
  RequestHeader set http_auth "Y2FuY3VuQG1ic2JiYW5rLmNvbScgJzExMTExMTExJyAnJDJhJDEyJDJwMlFOMVNZVURldUlpcWw2R3ZWMk83Mi45QUtXSlROcUlnWDRFQVUvZnJjU01SZnJNQXVL"
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

---

I have come to the end of the line with this one, I tried everything and I cannot get the request header to pass through.
.
I can either put my header in the JSON messages I send or move to nginx.

Since I have been using httpd for years I will take the first option.

---

I saw this post but I cannot add a comment due to reputation.

Is this relevant ?

If it is where do I put these instructions ?

---

It seems this line preserves the Header for reasons I don't quite understand:

SetEnvIf HTTP_MY_HEADER "(.*)" MY_HEADER=$0
The reason I don't understand this is that I am setting an Env var here, not a header -- are Env vars automatically turned into headers?

I though I might have to do this also, but was unnecessary:

RequestHeader set HTTP_MY_HEADER "${MY_HEADER}e"
I suppose this is an answer as "it works", although I would love to know why...

Comment: did you ever find a solution? It's a good question..